# SQL: Organizing summed data into two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, aggregate-filter

Let's say I have a dataset like:

```
DATE        PAGE_ID  HITS
2014-1-1    1        100
2014-1-1    2        50
2014-1-1    3        20
2014-1-2    1        20
2014-1-2    2        40
2014-1-2    3        20
```

I can currently use:

```
SELECT date, hits
FROM my_table
WHERE PAGE_ID = 1
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

To get daily stats for 1 page_id.

But how can I get a date aggregate for the pages, but in different columns? Like this:

```
DATE        Page_1_hits   All_other_pages
2014-1-1    100             70
2014-1-2    20              60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the current Postgres version (9.4)

```
select date, 
       sum(hits) filter (where page_id = 1) as page_1_hits,
       sum(hits) filter (where page_id <> 1) as all_other_pages
from my_table
group by date
order by date asc;
```

For earlier versions you need to use a `case`

```
select date, 
       sum(case when page_id = 1 then hits end) as page_1_hits,
       sum(case when page_id <> 1 then hits end) as all_other_pages
from my_table
group by date
order by date asc;
```

Comment: . . Do you know of any advantages in using the `filter` clause?  Is it in some future version of ANSI SQL?

Comment: btw there's a typo above, it should say "when hits end" not "hen hits end"

Comment: @GordonLinoff: that's not a "future" SQL standard. That  is the _current_ SQL standard I think it was introduced in the SQL:2003 standard. I think it's a bit clearer in terms of "documenting" your intention.And at least in this blog post it seems to be faster as well: http://www.cybertec.at/postgresql-9-4-aggregation-filters-they-do-pay-off/